# Drawing an isometric from a multiview

Tags: design

I'm very new to designing shapes in multi views and drawings and got a homework problem on this. I have to draw an isometric from this multiview drawing. I have no clue where to start and am not totally sure what all the lines on the drawing mean. Any help is appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Start with a cube on your desk, then represent it on the isometric grid - think how the form is represented. Then apply that to the object you have been given for homework.

Answer (score 1):

As this is a homework question, I have placed the answers behind image links, rather than embedding the images. Think of them like spoilers - once you have a looked at them, you can no longer un-see them, and you will not learn as much from your homework. Please try to work through the problem with help from your teachers/text books before consulting the 'answer key' below!

The first step in any drawing problem is to fully understand the form of the object at hand. If you're not completely comfortable with what the shape should be, then you need to keep examining the source material.

The actual process for converting those 2D drawings to ISO view, which is what your question seems to be about, primarily, is not at all easy to explain in a text-based format. I shot a quick video showing myself going through the process to create a hand-drawn ISO view from the information provided in your question sheet only. N.B. This was un-prepared, so there's a bit of erasing! I've tried to explain my thought processes as I went along. The only thing to note, is I didn't want to be obstructing the camera so opted not to use a ruler, but *you should always use a ruler* for this kind of exercise.

https://www.youtube.com/embed/OOJT2jYBj28

A line drawing with hidden edges, of the most useful Isometric view for showing the form of this object, in my opinion: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYmvp.png

Solid model views of of all possible isometric orientations. This will give you a clear understanding of the form of this object. https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OgbU.jpg